# R: How to improve the fit of a general linear mixed model in LME4?

Tags: r, model, statistics, lme4

Stack overflow question – model fit and selection for `glmer()` in `lme4`

I am still relatively new to this, and have tried everything I can think of and google but seem to have hit a wall, so sorry in advance if some of this is basic/incorrect. I don’t know if this should be broken up into several questions – but perhaps presenting it as one process is more helpful. What I really want to know is how can you tell that a model you have made is good enough to use for hypothesis testing and forming conclusions.

I am carrying out analysis of a large seedlings dynamics data set (20258 seedlings from 7467 plots) which I am unable to share for privacy reasons, as it is not my dataset. In this analysis, I am trying to determine how several explanatory variables (stem length, functional group, conspecific and heterospecific density, and the interactions between functional groups and density) affect the probability of survival for a given seedling - using the glmer() function in lme4.  Before using the model, I scaled all continuous variables using the scale() function and made sure all non-continuous variables were listed as factors and played around with optimizer settings and iteration number to get rid of some standard optimizer warnings.

The model is structured like this (AIC VALUE IS BELOW THE MODEL):

```
themod <- glmer(survival ~ stemlength + group + conspecific density + 
heterospecific density + group:conspecifics + group:heterospecifics 
+group:stemlength + (1|plot) + (1 + conspecifics + heterospecifics|species), 
family=binomial(link = "logit"), data = dataset, 
control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

AIC: 14040 (<2e-16) R squared fitted: 0.25441404 R squared random: 0.748984

I have tried several versions of these models on the same dataset and compared AIC values using anova (compared against the basemodel value of 14128.7 listed below) and dropterm analyses (which showed that all variables either improved the fit of the model or had no effect either way), and this one was the best fit to the data. I have also looked into using pseudo R squared values (as described in Nakawaga et al., 2013) - which seems to indicate that other models were better fits, but I stuck to using AIC values. See other models below – each listed with AIC and R squared values.

```
basemod <- glmer(survival ~ stemlength + conspecifics + heterospecifics + 
(1|plot) + (1|species),          family=binomial(link = "logit"), data = 
dataset, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",     
optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

AIC: 14128.7 R squared fitted: 0.09298017 R squared random: 0.489361

```
mod1 <- glmer(survival ~ stemlength + conspecifics + heterospecifics + group 
+ group:conspecifics + group:heterospecifics + (1|plot) + (1 + conspecifics 
+ heterospecifics|species), family=binomial, data = dataset, 
control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

AIC: 14086 (<2e-16) R squared fitted: 0.27126705 R squared random: 0.730059

```
mod2 <- glmer(survival ~ stemlength + conspecifics + heterospecifics + group 
+ (1|plot) + (1 + conspecifics + heterospecifics|species), family=binomial, 
data = dataset, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

AIC: 14128.7(<2e-16) R squared fitted: 0.35435996 R squared random: 0.798788

Having picked a formula for my model (here listed as themod) I began to test the fit. Following the advice of Bolker et al., 2009, I wanted to see if the data was homogenous across categories, but seeing as I have 7467 plots and 77 species split into two groups for 20258 seedlings, this seems infeasible? Perhaps it would be good to exclude those very rare species, i.e. those with very few individuals? I could also group plots to reduce the overall number – but as I'm using a general linear mixed model with a plot as a random effect, I think that grouping plots won’t make a difference?

I also wanted to see if “the responses of transformed data were linear with respect to continuous predictors” - from Bolker et al., 2009, which I took to mean that the continuous parameters are linear in log odds space - or that the output of the model (logodds), plotted against each of the three continuous variables (stemlength, conspecific density and heterospecific density) shows a linear relationship.  To do this I used this code to make these plots (click the link):

```
modvalues <- as.data.frame(cbind(predict(themod))) 
plot(modvalues$V1, dataset$stemlength, , xlab = "Log odds", ylab = "Stem 
length")
abline(lm(dataset$stemlength~modvalues$V1), col="red") 
plot(modvalues$V1, dataset$conspecifics, xlab = "Log odds", ylab = 
"Conspecific densities")
abline(lm(dataset$conspecifics~modvalues$V1), col="red")  
plot(modvalues$V1, dataset$heterospecifics, xlab = "Log odds", ylab = 
"Heterospecific densities") 
abline(lm(dataset$heterospecifics~modvalues$V1), col="red")
```

[Figures showing the relationship between the log odds and the continuous parameters of stemlength, conspecific density and heterospecific density](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gVHH.png)

However, these show a perhaps near linear relationship for stem length and conspecific density, but certainly not for heterospecific density. 
Third, I wanted to see if there were residual outliers, using further diagnostic plots generated using this code:

```
plot(themod, id=0.05,idLabels=~.obs) # shows us outliers
```

I removed these outliers using this code:

```
dfs <- dataset
dfs$resid <- resid(themod)
dfs$fitted <- fitted(themod)
z <- resid(m3)
z <- z[abs(z-mean(z))<2*sd(z)]
newdat <- dfs[dfs$resid %in% z, ] 
themod_noout <- update(themod, data=newdat)
```

This improved things but left some additional outliers that I tried to remove using this code:

```
newdat2 <- newdat
newdat2 <- newdat2[order(newdat2$resid), ]
newdat2 <- tail(newdat2, -10)
newdat2 <- head(newdat2, -10)
themod_noout2 <- update(themod_noout,data=newdat2)
```

But this led to a very strange pattern when examining the residuals? 
which did improve the linearity in log odds space for stem length and perhaps conspecific density – but not heterospecific density (see figures - click link below).

[Residual plots showing outliers of the original model (themod), the model after one load of outliers were removed, and the model after two loads were removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTBvm.png)

Finally, I wanted to know if distributions within groups matched assumed distribution (binomial) - which again meets the problem of having a very large data set with many categories, but seeing as survival can only be binomial perhaps this is not a problem?

But I have will put this as a second question as I can post no more links to images.

(I have also been through the worked examples from Bolker, 2015 (I can't post the link as I don't have the reputation   – but they are all for much smaller datasets and I'm struggling to apply all of this method to my process).

So, my questions are:
How do I select from my original model formula set ups/structures – using AIC, dropterm, R squared or diagnostic plots of residual distributions?

How should I compare homogeneity across categories and should I reduce my sample side, or exclude rare species?

Whats going on with my outliers?

Are any of these models actually good enough, and how do I tell?

Finally, if not – what can I do to improve them, and how could I restructure my model to do so?

Thanks so much to anyone who has the time and effort to go through all this, and again, apologies in advance for my ignorance. Cheers!

Comment: You might be interested in the **DHARMa** package for residual diagnostics for mixed models.  This question seems to be more about statistics than coding; you could consider moving it to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I have asked the question on cross validated. I will also have a look at DharMa on Monday. Cheers, Will.

Comment: you might also consider the [R-sig-mixed-models mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models) if you don't get a satisfactory answer on Cross-Validated